# How to use Flask to serve a React.js single page component

Tags: reactjs, flask, web-applications

I have an application that is largely tables and standard pages and forms.  However, I have one page this really need to be highly responsive that is probably best developed in React.js.

I would like to have a Flask + Jinja handle the delivery of most of the pages.  I understand Facebook does a bit of this with PhP for the majority of the site with React.js handing the responsive components.  Is there a Flask library that makes this simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use any library for this as it's pretty straightforward.

All you need to do is:

- Make that page using React.js and build the project to make bundle Javascript file which bootstraps the React.js page.
- Make `div` inside your jinja template and import that bundle javascript file.

Here, one important thing is to assign identical 'id' to the Jinja template `div` and React.js rendering `div`.